# Infinite geometric series question

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

This is something in the textbook I am reading:

Example 1.30. The geometric series $\sum_{1}^{\infty} x^{k}$ is convergent to $(1-x)^{-1}$ if $|x|<1$ and divergent otherwise.

My question is : isn't $\sum_{0}^{\infty} x^{k}$ is convergent to $(1-x)^{-1}$ if $|x|<1$ and $\sum_{1}^{\infty} x^{k}$ is convergent to $\frac{1}{1-x}-1=\frac{x}{1-x}$ if $|x|<1$
Thank you in advance for the help :)

Comment: That must be a typo in the book. What you are saying is correct.

Comment: Yes, your version is correct

Comment: Certainly, correct!